# Radius of convergence and absolute convergence

Tags: calculus

Say I have a power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ with a known radius of convergence $-1< x \leq 1$. What can I generally know about the series convergence in $x=1$? I'm asking because I've seen it can't converge absolutely in $x=1$ and I don't understand why.

Comment: You mean interval of convergence $(-1,1]$ ?

Comment: the definition of radius of convergence says nothing about convergence at $|x|$ equals radius. There are example for every kind of behavior, absolute or conditional convergence, or divergence to say $+\infty$ or not convergence at all. Wikipedia has some examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: It can converge absolutely at a point in the boundary. But to appreciate more all this, it is more interesting if one considers $x$ to be a complex number. Then the boundary of the circle of convergence (assuming the radius of convergence is $1$)  is a circle of radius one centered at the origin. What happens in the boundary can be really surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k.
$$
At points $\pm 1$ it diverges.

Consider series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2}.
$$
At points $\pm 1$ it converges.

Consider series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}.
$$
It converges at $-1$ and diverges at $1$.

For all series the radius of convergence are equal to $1$. So, anything can happen at the endpoints of the interval.

If the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \tag{1}
$$
converges absolutely at $x = 1$, then the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|
$$
converges and that's why (1) converges absolutely at $x=-1$ as well. So, if we have $(-1,1]$ as an interval of convergence, the convergence at the endpoint must be conditional.